# Echo selected value first

Tags: php, html, forms, html-select

I need to echo the selected value first in a form when user wants to make an update. I tried several variants:

1)

```
<?php 
  $opt= array('1' => 'opt1', '2' => 'opt2', '3' => 'opt3') ;
  echo '<select name="up_opt" >' ;

  foreach ($opt as $i => $value) {
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"";
    if ($_REQUEST['up_opt'] == $i) 
    {
      echo "selected" ; 
    }
    echo ">$opt[$i]</option>" ;
  }
  echo '</select>' ;
?>
```

2)

```
<?php $opt= array('1' => 'opt1', '2' => 'opt2', '3' => 'opt3') ;
  $edu = $_REQUEST['edu']; 
  <select name="up_opt">     
    <?php foreach ( $opt as $i=>$opt ) : ?>       
      <option value="<?php echo $i?>" <?php echo $i == $edu ? 'selected' : ''?>><?php echo $opt ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </select>
```

3)

```
<select name="up_opt">
    <option value="1" <?php if ($_GET['1'] == 'option1') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Opt1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($_GET['2'] == 'option2') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Opt2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($_GET['3'] == 'option3') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Opt3</option>
 </select>
```

None of these variants echoes the checked value first. Can someone help me, tell me what is wrong or give me another variant?

Comment: You need a space before selected in all examples

Comment: There's also multiple things wrong with each example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variant 3 is ok (but I'd rather use a loop instead of hard-coded options). Your mistake is that you compare 'option1', 'option2' and so one when your real values are '1', '2', '3'. Also as @ElefantPhace said, don't forget about spaces before **selected**, or you'll get invalid html instead. So it would be this:

```
<select name="up_opt">
    <option value="1" <?php if ($_GET['up_opt'] == 1) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Opt1</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($_GET['up_opt'] == 2) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Opt2</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($_GET['up_opt'] == 3) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Opt3</option>
</select>
```

With loop:

```
<?php

$options = array(
    1 => 'Opt1',
    2 => 'Opt2',
    3 => 'Opt3',
);

?>

<select name="up_opt">
<?php foreach ($options as $value => $label): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php if ($_GET['up_opt'] == 1) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $label; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Still wrong, there's no $_GET 1,2, or 3. Should be up_opt

Comment: @ElefantPhace yup, sorry, forget to add them.

Comment: The first is still the cleanest way to do it though

Comment: @user3080279 if any of our answers helped you, please, accept the right one.

Comment: @Hast, I think you have a good answer but how do you handle a situation if an index is initially undefined? It works great when the value is already in the database, but just prior to the time of insertion into a database it gives an error. Thanks

Comment: @kejo sorry, I don't quite understand your question. This question and my answer have nothing to do with the database so far.

Answer (score 0):

Here is all three of your variants, tested and working as expected. They are all basically the same, you were just using the wrong variable names, and different ones from example to example

1)

```
<?php
    $opt= array('1' => 'opt1', '2' => 'opt2', '3' => 'opt3') ;
    echo '<select name="up_opt">';
    foreach ($opt as $i => $value) {
        echo "<option value=\"$i\"";
        if ($_POST['up_opt'] == $i){
            echo " selected"; 
        }
        echo ">$value</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';
?>
```

2) uses same array as above

```
$edu = $_POST['up_opt']; 
echo '<select name="up_opt">';
foreach ( $opt as $i => $value ){       
    echo "<option value=\"$i\"", ($i == $edu) ? ' selected' : '';
    echo ">$value</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

3)

```
echo '<select name="up_opt">';
echo '<option value="1"', ($_POST['up_opt'] == '1') ? 'selected':'' ,'>Opt1</option>';
echo '<option value="2"', ($_POST['up_opt'] == '2') ? 'selected':'' ,'>Opt2</option>';
echo '<option value="3"', ($_POST['up_opt'] == '3') ? 'selected':'' ,'>Opt3</option>';
echo '</select>';
```